# What's the difference between these 2 pieces of Makefile.am code?

Tags: makefile, autotools, automake

I am completely new to using autotools so it might be a dumb question but I'll try anyway. I have two pieces of `Makefile.am`. Except one is working fine and the other is not.

This works fine.

```
sbin_PROGRAMS = kernel
kernel_SOURCES = \
    src/arch/$(host_cpu)/arch_sysdefs.h \
    src/arch/$(host_cpu)/boot.asm \
    src/arch/$(host_cpu)/cpu.asm \
    src/arch/$(host_cpu)/isr.asm \
    src/kmain.cpp
```

But this doesn't. `.asm` files are completely ignored by generated `Makefile`.

```
if HOST_CPU_X86
ASM_EXT = .asm
else
ASM_EXT = .S
endif

sbin_PROGRAMS = kernel
kernel_SOURCES = \
    src/arch/$(host_cpu)/arch_sysdefs.h \
    src/arch/$(host_cpu)/boot$(ASM_EXT) \
    src/arch/$(host_cpu)/cpu$(ASM_EXT) \
    src/arch/$(host_cpu)/isr$(ASM_EXT) \
    src/kmain.cpp
```

What I am trying to do is that I want to use different suffixes for assembly files for some CPUs my project is going to support.

I've also added necessary rule to transform `.asm` to object files.

```
.asm.o:
    yasm -f $(YASM_OUT_FMT) $< -o $@
```

EDIT: Temporarily overriding `.cpp.o` rule with `echo $(kernel_SOURCES)` reveals that `$(ASM_EXT)` in `kernel_SOURCES` is substituted correctly. For example `src/arch/$(host_cpu)/boot$(ASM_EXT)` becomes `src/arch/x86_64/boot.asm` for x86-64 CPU and `src/arch/arm/boot.S` for ARM, etc. Also, setting `ASM_EXT` variable from autoconf.ac doesn't make any difference.